# How to declare class name with arraylist value?

Tags: java

I'm new on java, and I'm trying to declare ArrayList's value as a class name.
But I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's some example what I intended to.
(Book is class having some constructor);

```
        ArrList.add("bookNum"+i);
        Book ArrList.get(i) = new Book("title", (int)price,"author");
```

Is there any method to this ?

Why I'm trying to do like this is there's lot of name will inputed, and I want to make each instance instantly, and dynamically.

Comment: trying to find out something correct with that code

Comment: have a look at the javadocs for ArrayList, I am sure that there will be a good method to use

Comment: Sorry but this is incomprehensible.  What is an "ArrayList's value"?  That is the list right?  How can a list be a method name?  Or assuming that you mean an **element** of the list ... how can a `Book` be a method, or a method name.  Or maybe you are talking about a name (title) of a book, but how is it sensible for that to be the name of a method?

Comment: *"Why I'm trying to do like this is there's lot of name will inputed, and I want to make each instance instantly, and dynamically."* - the `new` operator makes an instance "instantly and dynamically".  It does not require you to declare methods ... or even variables ... to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write enough for explaining my question. ArrList is having String values like bookNum1, bookNum2, etc.. and Book is some method I made for this program.

Comment: `Book` is NOT a method.  It is a class.  If you want people to understand what you are saying you need to use the correct terms.

Comment: So I want to input a value(bookNum1, .. ) to ArrList, and use that element as a new instance name of Book.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused of the word class, method, instance ;; Sorry I'll edit it

Comment: Guys, he wants a `Map<String, Book>`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about how to create dynamic *variables* in Java.  That is not possible.  Java does not support dynamic variables.

---

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
int bookID = 1;

Map<String, Book> books = new HashMap<>();
while (...) {
    ...
    Book book = new Book(title, price, author);
    books.put("book-" + (bookID++), book);
}

Book temp = books.get("book-42");
System.out.println("Book 42 is " + temp.getTitle());
```

As you can see, the `Map` allows to record multiple name -> book mappings, and it also allows us to lookup books by name.  That's as close as you will get to dynamic variables in Java.

Now you could use an `ArrayList` ... but that would be a mistake.  A `List` just holds things.  It does not associate things (e.g. names) with other things (e.g. books).  To represent an association (or relationship) you need to use a `Map`.

---

Note that this is just a starter.  For more information, please read the javadocs for `Map` and `HashMap`.  In particular, read about what happens if the `get` operation cannot find a key ...

Comment: I'd say `#computeIfAbsent` could be useful here but I don't know if that would just make it more confusing

Comment: thanks for your answer. I appreciate your help.
But what i intened to is making another instance like

Book book1 = new Book(title, price, author);
Book book2 = new Book(title, price, author);

Comment: Yes, that's what this code does. It makes numerous book instances and puts them in the Map (which is like a list, but you can look things up by keys like `"book-1"` instead of index numbers)

Comment: @Rogue ... yes, I think it would.